# Dapper with transactions throws "open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, dapper

Very intermittently I am getting `InvalidOperationException` "open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first"

This is a too long mission critical piece of code that was a stored procedure and probably still should be but a number of years ago I converted it to Dapper calls with a transaction to abandon it all if one part failed.

I have seen several several SO questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439124/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690147/entity-framework-error-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this) which are solved with a `ToList()` however, I'm using `AsList()` on a query result which only calls a logger call to Azure Table storage and a for loop on a parameter List so didn't think those applied here.

I'm also using the EF6 DBContext connection rather than the creating a standard SqlConnection which may just fix this but don't wish the change without understanding the issue first.

This method runs hundreds of times a day, every day without fail but when it throws this exception, a customer is locked out from re-running this for at least 15 minutes.

```cs
public async Task<int> LinkJob(int customerId, int jobId, int employeeId, List<TaskDto> tasks)
{
    var conn = _context.Database.Connection;
    conn.Open();

    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var checks = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(@" 
    SELECT Id FROM Customer 
    WHERE Id = @customerId
    SELECT Id FROM Job WHERE Id = @jobId
            ", new { customerId, jobId }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction);

            var customer = (await checks.ReadAsync<int?>()).SingleOrDefault();
            if (customer == null)
            {
                throw new ServiceNotFoundException($"Customer {customerId} not found");
            }

            var job = (await checks.ReadAsync<JobDto>()).SingleOrDefault();
            if (job == null)
            {
                throw new ServiceNotFoundException($"Job {jobId} not found");
            }

            var workItemId = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(@"
    DECLARE @WorkItemId int
    INSERT WorkItem (CustomerId, JobId, JobDate)
    VALUES (@customerId, @job, GETDATE())
    SELECT @WorkItemId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    IF @CustomerId > 0
        UPDATE Customer SET LatestActionDate = GETDATE() WHERE Id = @CustomerId
    SELECT @WorkItemId
            ", new { customerId, jobId }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction)).SingleOrDefault();

            await _auditLogger.LogJob(jobId, "Job created", user);

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Sum(o => o.ItemCount * o.Required); i++)
            {
                var taskId = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(@"
    INSERT Task (JobId, Cost,) VALUES (@jobId, @Cost)
    SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE Id = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
                ", new { jobId, job.Cost }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction));
            }

            await conn.ExecuteAsync(@"
    //do another insert here
                        ", new { jobId }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction);

            var tasksDT = tasks.Select(o => new { o.TaskTypeId, o.Required 
    }).ToDataTable();

            var allocatedTasks = (await conn.QueryAsync<TaskDetailsDto>(@"
    --Complex cte insert that returns some details to log

            ", new { taskAllocationckId, jobId, Tasks = tasksDT.AsTableValuedParameter("TasksUDT") 
    }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction)).AsList();

            foreach(var task in allocatedTasks)
            {
                await _auditLogger.LogJob(jobId, $"{task.TaskTypeName} task added with `enter code here`{task.ItemCount} items");
            }

            transaction.Commit();

            return workItemId;
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't running multiple awaits on same connection executions mean that one connection can be running multiple statements at the same time? I'm not well versed in C# though, but it sounds like that could lead to trouble

Comment: all I can see right away is that you variable `checks` needs to be disposed, preferably before any other queries on the same connection, so use the usin gwith curly braces

Comment: @siggemannen yes, probably a bit of async abuse.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek the checks doesn't even need to be in the transaction so could be in it's own method and be disposed but hoped someone would see a smoking gun for this exception before I refactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `using` on `checks`, which is holding a reference to the reader. This must use braces in order to dispose at the correct point.

Further issues:

- You are using `QueryAsync` instead of `QueryFirstAsync` in the `taskId` bit.
- You can use `OUTPUT` instead of a separate `SELECT` in the same section.
- You don't need to `catch` and `Rollback`, the `using` will do that.
- The connection also needs a `using`, and you should create a new one rather than using the one from EF Core.
- Open the connection and create the transaction asynchronously also.
- Use shorter syntax such as `using` statements without braces where possible, and `?? throw` for the null checks.
- Do not use `AsList`, it only checks for `List<T>` it does not convert and does not dispose.

```sql
public async Task<int> LinkJob(int customerId, int jobId, int employeeId, List<TaskDto> tasks)
{
    await using var conn = CreateNewConnection();
    await conn.OpenAsync();

    await using var transaction = conn.BeginTransactionAsync();

    int customer, JobDto job;
    await (using var checks = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(@" 
    SELECT Id FROM Customer 
    WHERE Id = @customerId;
    SELECT Id FROM Job WHERE Id = @jobId;
            ", new { customerId, jobId }, transaction))
    {
        customer = (await checks.ReadAsync<int?>()).SingleOrDefault()
            ?? throw new ServiceNotFoundException($"Customer {customerId} not found");

        job = (await checks.ReadAsync<JobDto>()).SingleOrDefault()
            ?? throw new ServiceNotFoundException($"Job {jobId} not found");
    }

    var workItemId = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(@"
    INSERT WorkItem (CustomerId, JobId, JobDate)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id
    VALUES (@customerId, @job, GETDATE());

    IF @CustomerId > 0
        UPDATE Customer
        SET LatestActionDate = GETDATE()
        WHERE Id = @CustomerId;
            ", new { customerId, jobId }, transaction)).SingleOrDefault();

    await _auditLogger.LogJob(jobId, "Job created", user);

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Sum(o => o.ItemCount * o.Required); i++)
    {
        var taskId = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(@"
    INSERT Task (JobId, Cost)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id
    VALUES (@jobId, @Cost);
        ", new { jobId, job.Cost }, transaction));

        // do something with taskId
    }

    await conn.ExecuteAsync(@"
    //do another insert here
                        ", new { jobId }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction);

    var tasksDT = tasks.Select(o => new { o.TaskTypeId, o.Required 
    }).ToDataTable();

    var allocatedTasks = (await conn.QueryAsync<TaskDetailsDto>(@"
    --Complex cte insert that returns some details to log

            ", new { taskAllocationckId, jobId, Tasks = tasksDT.AsTableValuedParameter("TasksUDT") 
    }, transaction.UnderlyingTransaction)).ToListAsync();

    foreach(var task in allocatedTasks)
    {
        await _auditLogger.LogJob(jobId, $"{task.TaskTypeName} task added with {task.ItemCount} items");
    }

    await transaction.CommitAsync();

    return workItemId;
}
```

You can also replace the entire `taskId` loop with a single insert, using `GENERATE_SERIES` or on older versions you can use [a numbers function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).

```cs
var taskIdList = (await conn.QueryAsync<int>(@"
    INSERT Task (JobId, Cost)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id
    SELECT @jobId, @Cost
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, @Count);
        ", new { jobId, job.Cost, Count = tasks.Sum(o => o.ItemCount * o.Required) }, transaction)).ToListAsync();

// do something with taskId
```

It's hard to tell exactly given your stripped-down code, but you could probably do this entire set of commands in a single SQL batch.

Comment: Thanks, I think the logic to move it from a single SQL batch to code was to have it in source control and log during the process but as you say, likely better that way.

I'll give this a go but likely these improvements will sort things

Comment: this whole thread just shows me that EF Core isn't that bad :D the performance difference would need to be HUGE to convince me it's worth dabbing into raw sql like this

Comment: I find it tends to be that certain types of joins and apply constructs, and things like `OUTPUT` are simply not possible in EF Core. Also it often adds in unnecessary joins due to the model, which can be difficult to avoid. The difference in performance can indeed be huge sometimes, even on a relatively small DB.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek I tend to use EF where possible too and anything that needs to be really fast goes into Dapper. This code has a cte, cross apply and bulk insert that couldn't easily be done in EF6 at the time